# Loki groups rules get content log

Tags: grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, grafana-loki

I want to notify when a log type error occurs and send its log content, will it be possible to add it in the labels or annotations of the loki rules and send it to alertmanager?

This would be my test rule, but I still don’t see how to add the content of the registry

```
groups:
  - name: rate-alerting
    rules:
      - alert: testRule
        expr: |
          sum by (message)
            (rate({app="_development"} | json | level = "error"[1m] ))
            > 0.02
        for: 1m
        labels:
            severity:...
            team: ...
            category: ...
        annotations:
            title: "title Alert"
            description: "content log"
```

I would like to be able to obtain the content of the log to be able to notify it

Comment: Could you use text instead of images, please?

Answer (score 0):

You are groupping by message, so you can use it in the annotation, e.g:

```
annotations: 
    description: "{{ $labels.message }}"
```

Whole log line is not available in your query, so you can't use it.

Comment: and how could I add the complete line to my query? Is it possible to do that?